# How to plot the derivative of a non-analytic integral?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics

I have such integral expression

```
Re[2/(1 + 1/(2 Pi)*
    Integrate[(Cos[x] - h - I*Sin[x])/Abs[Cos[x] - h - I*Sin[x]], {x, 
      0, 2 Pi}])]
```

How can I plot the second derivative of above expression with respect to h? The range of h I want is from 0 to 2.

(Mathematica can not obtain an analytic expression for above integral)

Comment: `h` is real? $\phantom{}$

Comment: @J.M. Yes. $\phantom{}$

Comment: After a bit of coaxing *Mathematica*, I was able to obtain `(2 π (h (1 + h)^3 EllipticE[(4 h)/(1 + h)^2]^2 + (1 + h)^2 EllipticE[(4 h)/(1 + h)^2] ((h^2 - 2) π - 4 h (h - 1) EllipticK[(4 h)/(1 + h)^2]) + (h - 1) EllipticK[(4 h)/(1 + h)^2] (h (5 + 3 h^2) EllipticK[(4 h)/(1 + h)^2] - π (1 + h) (2 + h^2))))/((h - 1) (1 + h)^2 (h π - (1 + h) EllipticE[(4 h)/(1 + h)^2] + (1 - h) EllipticK[(4 h)/(1 + h)^2])^3)` as an expression for the second derivative. I will try writing up an elaboration (much) later, but you can at least try comparing it against Sneeze's answer.

Comment: @J.M. This explains the singularity at $h=1$. The numerical result seems so coarse in comparison!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can do everything analytically:

**Simplification of the integral**

```
ir = ComplexExpand[Re[(Cos[x] - h - I*Sin[x])/Abs[Cos[x] - h - I*Sin[x]]]] // Simplify
ii = ComplexExpand[Im[(Cos[x] - h - I*Sin[x])/Abs[Cos[x] - h - I*Sin[x]]]] // Simplify
```

$$\frac{\cos (x)-h}{\sqrt{h^2-2 h \cos (x)+1}}$$
$$-\frac{\sin (x)}{\sqrt{h^2-2 h \cos (x)+1}}$$

**Integration of the imaginary part (longer calculation)**

```
Integrate[-(Sin[x]/Sqrt[1 + h^2 - 2 h Cos[x]]), {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Assumptions -> h > 0]
*(ConditionalExpression[0, h != 1]*)
```

**Integration of the real part** is better to do by using the fundamental calculus theorem, one must verify that the integral is a continuous function. Therefore

```
k = Integrate[(-h + Cos[x])/Sqrt[1 + h^2 - 2 h Cos[x]], x, Assumptions -> h > 0]
ik = Simplify[(k /. {x -> 2 Pi}) - (k /. {x -> 0})]
```

$$-\frac{2 (h-1) \left((h+1) K\left(-\frac{4 h}{(h-1)^2}\right)+(h-1) E\left(-\frac{4 h}{(h-1)^2}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{(h-1)^2} h}$$

This can be simplified using the [imaginary modulus transformations](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.7.E5) for the complete elliptic integrals $K$ and $E$:

```
ik = Simplify[ik /. {EllipticK[m_] :> 1/Sqrt[1 - m] EllipticK[m/(m - 1)], 
                     EllipticE[m_] :> Sqrt[1 - m] EllipticE[m/(m - 1)]}, 
              h ∈ Reals]
```

$$-\frac{2 (h+1) \left((h-1) K\left(\frac{4 h}{(h+1)^2}\right)+(h+1) E\left(\frac{4 h}{(h+1)^2}\right)\right)}{h\left|h+1\right|}$$

which gets rid of the negative arguments in the complete integrals.

**Second derivative**

```
sk = FullSimplify[D[(4 Pi)/(ik + 2 Pi) /. Abs[m_] :> Sqrt[m^2], {h, 2}], 
                  Assumptions -> h > 0]
```

$$\small \frac{2 \pi  \left((h-1) K\left(\frac{4 h}{(h+1)^2}\right) \left(h \left(3 h^2+5\right) K\left(\frac{4 h}{(h+1)^2}\right)-\pi (h+1) \left(h^2+2\right)\right)+(h+1)^2 \left(\pi \left(h^2-2\right)-4 (h-1) h K\left(\frac{4 h}{(h+1)^2}\right)\right) E\left(\frac{4 h}{(h+1)^2}\right)+h (h+1)^3 E\left(\frac{4 h}{(h+1)^2}\right)^2\right)}{(h-1) (h+1)^2 \left(-(h-1) K\left(\frac{4 h}{(h+1)^2}\right)+\pi  h-(h+1) E\left(\frac{4 h}{(h+1)^2}\right)\right)^3}$$

**Plot**

```
Plot[sk, {h, 0., 2.}]
```

[image: plot of the function]

Comment: Looks like I don't need to write an answer anymore. I will only add that the two complete elliptic integrals can be further simplified for $h>0$ by using the [imaginary modulus transformations](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.7.E5): `{EllipticK[m_] :> 1/Sqrt[1 - m] EllipticK[m/(m - 1)], EllipticE[m_] :> Sqrt[1 - m] EllipticE[m/(m - 1)]}`

Comment: @J.M. If you already have a simplified solution and you do not want to write your own you are welcome to amend mine.

Comment: Great! Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @yarchik, I've added the simplifications; feel free to edit it further so that it looks more like your writing style.

Comment: @J.M. Very nice, it looks much more concise now.

Answer (score 2):

### Update

I was complicating matters. No need to split:

```
ClearAll[f, int, g];
f[x_, h_] := Sign[Cos[x] - h - I Sin[x]]
int[h_] := NIntegrate[f[x, h], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
g[h_?NumericQ] := Re[2/(1 + 1/(2 Pi) int[h])]

Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
Plot[ND[g[h], {h, 2}, h0], {h0, 0, 2}]
```

Taking $69$sec with no message:

> [image]

Oscillating is perhaps due to numerical integration.

### Original

Hints rather than an answer:

- Split the integral into real & imaginary parts so as to perform `NIntegrate` on each?
- Use of the numerical version of `D` — `` NumericalCalculus`ND ``?

```
ClearAll[f, int, g];
f[x_, h_] := (Cos[x] - h - I Sin[x])/Abs[Cos[x] - h - I Sin[x]]
int[h_] := 
 NIntegrate[Re[f[x, h]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}] + 
  I*NIntegrate[Im[f[x, h]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
g[h_?NumericQ] := Re[2/(1 + 1/(2 Pi) int[h])]

Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
Plot[ND[g[h], {h, 2}, h0], {h0, 1, 2}]
```

But still lots of messages emerge. 2 minutes later I got the plot on interval $[1,2]$:

> [image]

Hope this satisfies OP's need. :)

Comment: Thanks! Actually I want the plot to be range from 0 to 2 for h0. I copied you code and ran it on my computer. I got some weird shape around h0=1.

Comment: @lol Also wondering why...

Comment: I expected that there is a discontinuity around h0=1 for second derivative

Answer (score 2):

A method to proceede if there is no analytical solution for the integral and to get very good results.

Generate an interpolating function of h you can easily differentiate where you don't need further numerical integrations when you differentiate.

Therefore differentate the integrand for h, integrate for x, that means i interchanged integration:
`(*  int[h_] = NIntegrate[integrand[x,h],{x,0,2 Pi}]->  ipfunction[h_] = NDSolve[NIntegrate[D[integrand[x,h],h],{x,0,2 \ Pi}],{h,hmin,hmax}]   *)`

```
ceall = (Cos[x] - h - I*Sin[x])/Abs[Cos[x] - h - I*Sin[x]] // 
  ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // 
  FullSimplify[#, {0 <= x <= 2 Pi, h \[Element] Reals}] &

ddh[x_, h_] = 
  D[ceall, h] // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // 
  FullSimplify[#, {0 <= x <= 2 Pi, h \[Element] Reals}] &

ddint[h_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[ddh[x, h], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, MaxRecursion -> 100] // Chop // Quiet

(dssol = ds /. 
First@NDSolve[{ds'[h] == ddint[h], ds[0] == 0}, 
  ds, {h, -2, 2}]) // AbsoluteTiming

Plot[dssol[h] // Chop, {h, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All]

rr2[h_] = 2/(1 + 1/(2 Pi)*dssol[h]) // Simplify

dd2[h_] = D[rr2[h], {h, 2}]
```

Compare it with the anylytical solution dd[h] (i don't derive, e.g. @yarchik did it)

```
dd[h_] = -(2*Pi*Abs[-1 + h]*
      ((-1 + h)^3*h*EllipticE[-((4*h)/(-1 + h)^2)]^2 + 
         (-1 + h)*EllipticE[-((4*h)/(-1 + h)^2)]*
           ((-2 + h^2)*Pi*Abs[-1 + h] - 4*h*(-1 + h^2)*
                EllipticK[-((4*h)/(-1 + h)^2)]) + 
         (1 + h)*EllipticK[-((4*h)/(-1 + h)^2)]*
           ((-(2 + h^2))*Pi*Abs[-1 + h] + h*(5 + 3*h^2)*
                EllipticK[-((4*h)/(-1 + h)^2)])))/
 ((1 + h)*((-h)*Pi*Abs[-1 + h] + (-1 + h)^2*
           EllipticE[-((4*h)/(-1 + h)^2)] + 
         (-1 + h^2)*EllipticK[-((4*h)/(-1 + h)^2)])^3)

Plot[{dd[h], Chop[dd2[h]]}, {h, -2, 2}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Opacity[.3], Thickness[.02], Red}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for comparing numerical and analytical solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing I'm a little bit late, here a straightforward numerical solution.

First define the integral

```
int = Function[h,NIntegrate[(-h + Cos[x] - I Sin[x])/Sqrt[1 + h^2 - 2 h Cos[x]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]]
```

Second define the second derivative

```
d2 = Function[h,Re@Derivative[2][Function[h, 2/(1 + int[h]/(2 Pi))]][h]]
```

Plot result

```
Plot[d2[h], {h, 0, 2}]
```

[image]